Suspicion of the proof: For holomorphic function $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$, $|a_n|r^n \le 2 \max_{|z|=r} \text{Re}f(z)-2 \text{Re} f(0)$.

For holomorphic function $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$, $|a_n|r^n \le 2 \max_{|z|=r} \text{Re}f(z)-2 \text{Re} f(0)$.

The above problem has been proved in For holomorphic function $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$, $|a_n|r^n \le 2 \max_{|z|=r} \text{Re}f(z)-2 \text{Re} f(0)$.
But I have a problem. Let us firt see the proof by @user515010:

Recall that for every $k\in\mathbb{C}, m\in\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$ we have $$\int_0^{2\pi}ke^{im\vartheta}=0$$
So
$$ a_nr^n=\frac1\pi \int_0^{2\pi}\Re(f)(e^{i\vartheta})e^{-in\vartheta}d\vartheta=\frac1\pi\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\Re(f)(e^{i\vartheta})-\Re(f)(0)\right)e^{-in\vartheta}d\vartheta\\
|a_nr^n|\le 2|A(r)-\Re(f(0))|$$
As the right hand side must be positive by the maximum modulus principle for harmonic functions, the result follows:
$$|a_n|r^n\le 2A(r)-2\Re(f(0))$$


My problem is that:

from $$ a_nr^n=\frac1\pi \int_0^{2\pi}\Re(f)(e^{i\vartheta})e^{-in\vartheta}d\vartheta=\frac1\pi\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\Re(f)(re^{i\vartheta})-\Re(f)(0)\right)e^{-in\vartheta}d\vartheta$$
we can only deduce that  $$|a_nr^n|\le 2\max_{|z|=r}|\Re f(z)-\Re(f(0))|(\star)$$, but not that of $$|a_nr^n|\le 2|\max_{|z|=r}\Re f(z)-\Re(f(0))|(?)$$.

So how can we delete the abolute value to get $|a_nr^n|\le 2[A(r)-\Re f(0)]$?

I have tried and also noticed by @conrad the following: Let $a_n=|a_n|e^{i\tau}$, then
$$r^n|a_n|=r^na_ne^{-i\tau}
=\frac1\pi \int_0^{2\pi}\Re(f)(e^{i\vartheta})e^{-i(n\vartheta+\tau)}d\vartheta$$
Taking the real part gives
$$r^n|a_n|=\frac1\pi \int_0^{2\pi}\Re(f)(e^{i\vartheta})\cos(n\vartheta+\tau)d\vartheta
=\frac1\pi \int_0^{2\pi}[\Re(f)(e^{i\vartheta})-\Re f(0)]\cos(n\vartheta+\tau)d\vartheta$$
The integrand is still has no fixed sign. If we estimate it by the calculus method, we have still $(\star)$ as above!

Further,
$$r^n|a_n|=\frac1\pi \int_0^{2\pi}[\Re(f)(e^{i\vartheta})-\Re f(0)] [1+\cos(n\vartheta+\tau)]d\vartheta\\
=[\Re(f)(e^{i\phi})-\Re f(0)] \frac1\pi \int_0^{2\pi}[1+\cos(n\vartheta+\tau)]d\vartheta$$
by the integral mean value theorem.
Then
$$r^n|a_n|\leq [A(r)-\Re f(0)] \frac1{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}2d\vartheta=4[A(r)-\Re f(0)] $$
but not $2$!

$\Re f$ is harmonic so maximum modulus applies hence the RHS is positive so no absolute value needed

@Conrad But we get $(*)$, not $(?)$ the equation I have cited.

Yes now I get your point and it's valid- the correction is not difficult though; fix $n$ and pick $t_n$ st $a_nr^ne^{it_n}=|a_n|r^n$ and multiply the integral by that and put the $e^{it_n}$ inside the integral making it positive so it is equal to its real part and then we just use that for a non negative real integral, its value is at most the (automatically nonnegative) supremum of the integrand (times the length) to conclude

@Conrad I have tried your method before, but still could not get accross the difficulty...See the added equations.

Yes but note that if $P=\Re f-Re f(0)$ we have that $P$ averages to zero on the unit circle so the integral you correctly have of $P\cos (n\theta+\tau)$ is the same as the integral of $P(1+\cos(n\theta+\tau)$ and now the multiplier is nonnegative so you can replace $P$ by maximum of $P$, take it outside and be done - agree that the proof is a bit subtler than presented above so a good question indeed

@Conrad If I used your method, we get $4$, as I have added.

@Conrad The integral of that $\cos$ is $0$! So we get it!

Excellent! So hopefully the above helped
